# Removing .htaccess password protection in my site

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I disable password authentication on my site? I commented the following lines on my .htaccess file but my site still requires username password?

Or am I doing it wrong?

```
#AuthName "root"
#AuthUserFile "/home/myuser/.htpasswds/.htpasswd"
#AuthType Basic
#require valid-user
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Undo Commenting, and just add

```
Satisfy Any
```

On the very top of .htaccess

Comment: Ooh this was asked two year ago :|

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
```

Comment: so i will do this aside from commenting the lines i specified above?

Comment: Yes, you can either add my code below the commented section, or remove the commented section entirely and just have my code.

Comment: i had internal server error when i do : http://pastie.org/private/erjmkns77yhikrqzm8rsvg